# to select top MAX 10 measure in mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx, analysisservices

I am trying to select top max 10 measure in MDX and I get this ,what I have to do to get top 10 max.

```
     With
    Set [Top10] AS
    (TOPCOUNT({ORDER( ({[Customer].[Customer State]})
     ,([Measures].[Customers Quantity]),BDESC)},10))
    Select
    [Measures].[Customers Quantity] on Columns,
    {[Top10]}  on Rows
    From
    [DW Brazillian Ecommerce]
```

and I get this

[image]

I know what I did is wrong so what is the accurate query to get top 10 max customer quantity??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `[Customer].[Customer State]` to `[Customer].[Customer State].[Customer State].Members`. In the current expression you are just ranking the grand total. This change fixes the problem.